# How do you make an accumulated list into a non-accumulated list in python?

Tags: python, list

If there is a list `A = [1, 4, 10]` I want to change the list A into `A = [1, 3, 6]` where:

- `1` would stay the same,
- `4` would be `4 - 1 = 3`,
- `10` would be `10 - 4 = 6`

How can I do this?
So far, I have done

```
A = [1, 4, 10]
for i, num in enumerate(A):
    if i == 0:
        A[i] = A[0]
    else:
        A[i] = A[i] - A[i-1]
print(A)
```

but the printed `A` would be `[1, 3, 7]`

Comment: start subtracting from end elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
A = [1, 4, 10]

for i, num in enumerate(A[1:]):
    idx = len(A)-1 - i
    A[idx] = A[idx] - A[idx-1]
print(A)
# [1, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip`:

```
A = [1, 4, 10]
A = [A[0]] + [x2 - x1 for (x1, x2) in zip(A, A[1:])]
```

---

**A:**

```
[1, 3, 6]
```